# Same header on each web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'd like to be able to make a header for a webpage (think perhaps a menu bar) that is consistent throughout the entire website.

Is there any way with ASP.NET to use the same form on multiple different pages with some small differences? If so how?

Comment: Master pages. Look it up.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use a master page. This comes in handy when dealing with pages that look similar but may have different controls on it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a master page as suggested @Humpy, You have also an other way with a custom web control.

In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer Add new Element of type .ascx. A .ascx file is a partial element of aspx page.

In your web.config add  section for declare your web control ascx.
You can consume the ascx web control in multiple aspx pages.

It's an other solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7698y1f0(v=vs.85).aspx